# Criação automática de SCHEMA no postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

estou tendo um problema com o seguinte, preciso criar uma trigger que quando uma determinada linha é inserida ela cria um SCHEMA com uma estrutura especifica!
Por exemplo, no esquema public, eu tenho a tabela cliente, e quando eu inserir algum cliente, eu preciso criar uma trigger com o nome do cliente.

```
INSERT INTO public.cliente (idcliente, nome) VALUES (2,'joao');
```

Nesse caso, ele criaria automaticamente um SCHEMA com o nome de joão, mas eu não tenho idéia de como fazer isso.

Preciso criar uma função que recebe o nome do SCHEMA como parâmetro e dentro desta função criar o SCHEMA?

Comment: Que coisa estranha, hein? Isto parece algo muito errado.

Comment: Qual a finalidade de criar um schema novo a cada registro?

Comment: Na verdade, é que cada usuário de um determinado sistema vai ter o seu próprio SCHEMA, não fui eu quem criou essa regra e se fosse por mim eu não faria assim também.

Answer (score 0):

O jeito mais rápido é fazendo um script com alguma linguagem desejada.

Exemplo em PHP:

```
// faz a conexão normal;

$VariavelQueRecebeNome = 'joao';

// executa o insert normalmente;

$sCriarSchema = "CREATE SCHEMA ".$VariavelQueRecebeNome."; ";

$rsQuery = pg_query($sCriarSchema);
```

Há "n" formas de fazer;

Comment: Eu pensei exatamente nisso, mas fui indagado a fazer uma trigger, o que me ajuda também a aprender um pouco mais sobre triggers